# React-Native-Popup-Menu with FloatingActionButton Component cannot trigger with MenuTrigger

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-popup-menu

I would like to use [react-native-popup-menu](https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu) and [react-native-floating-action-button](https://github.com/WrathChaos/react-native-floating-action-button) components together. I've tried :

```
<MenuTrigger>
    <FloatingActionButton
        size={56}
        textDisable
        iconName="directions"
        iconType="material-icons"
        shadowColor="#000"
        iconColor="white"
        backgroundColor="#405914"
    />
</MenuTrigger>
```

This code does not trigger the MenuTrigger because FloatingActionButton's onPress is triggered.

---

I also tried this kinds of stuff :

```
<MenuTrigger customStyles={{ TriggerTouchableComponent: FloatingActionButton }} />
```

This one's trigger is working with MenuTrigger but I cannot customize the FAB button's styling.

Can you provide me a solution ?  :)

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

According to [doc](https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu/blob/master/doc/api.md#custom-styles-1) you could use `triggerTouchable`.

```
      <MenuTrigger
        customStyles={{
          TriggerTouchableComponent: Button,
          triggerTouchable: { title: 'Select (Custom Touchables)' },
        }}
      />
```

Comment: your post does not use `triggerTouchable`. I encourage you also to try official examples mentioned in doc.

Comment: I also tried it with triggerTouchable but could not trigger the Menu. Thanks anyway

Comment: Touchable component needs provide `onPress` property in order to "trigger" menu

Comment: I know, I also read the doc thank you :) Have you ever check FAB component? It has a onPress property but still not trigger the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Using `react-native-popup-menu` version 0.15.12 I am able now to achieve this with

```
<MenuTrigger>
  <MyCustomButtonComponent>
    <Icon ...>
  </MyCustomButtonComponent>
</MenuTrigger>
```